# ZF2 Form Collection, Fieldset with Files

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

The html is this...

```
<div class="control-group" id="control-group-url_imagem">
   <label class="control-label" for="url_imagem">Imagem</label>
   <div class="controls" id="controls-url_imagem">
     <input name="banners[0][url_imagem]" id="url_imagem" type="file">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group" id="control-group-url_imagem">
   <label class="control-label" for="url_imagem">Imagem</label>
   <div class="controls" id="controls-url_imagem">
     <input name="banners[1][url_imagem]" id="url_imagem" type="file">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group" id="control-group-url_imagem">
   <label class="control-label" for="url_imagem">Imagem</label>
   <div class="controls" id="controls-url_imagem">
     <input name="banners[2][url_imagem]" id="url_imagem" type="file">
   </div>
</div>
```

But when i submit the form the $adapter->getFileInfo() is:

```
[banners_0_] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [url_imagem] => 20130221_094918.jpg
            )

        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [url_imagem] => /tmp/phpVy2QwP
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [url_imagem] => 0
            )

        [size] => 
        [options] => Array
            (
                [ignoreNoFile] => 
                [useByteString] => 1
                [magicFile] => 
                [detectInfos] => 1
            )

        [validated] => 
        [received] => 
        [filtered] => 
        [validators] => Array
            (
                [0] => Zend\Validator\File\Upload
            )

    )
```

So it show me error because when the Http() try to 
Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string

the problem is it should not to be

```
[name] => Array
        (
            [url_imagem] => 20130221_094918.jpg
        )
```

It should be

```
 [name] => 20130221_094918.jpg
```

When i print $_FILES i get this

```
[banners] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 20130221_094918.jpg
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 
                    )

            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => image/jpeg
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 
                    )

            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => /tmp/phpC6G9t2
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 
                    )

            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 4
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 4
                    )

            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 3753164
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [url_imagem] => 0
                    )

            )

    )
```

Here is the full code https://gist.github.com/gpfiel/6355711

Im using AdicionarAction and uploadImageAndResize...

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html As stated in the doc/note u should allways merge the post and use the request method to retrieve the $_FILE.
 $post = array_merge_recursive(
            $request->getPost()->toArray(),
            $request->getFiles()->toArray()
        );